# How to test filter-like Ruby scripts with Pry?

Tags: ruby, bash, pipe, stdin, pry

I have a simple script which process the lines coming from STDIN. Sometimes an exception arise - some UTF-8 conversion error - and I would like to examine the variables, what cause the error. I use the following syntax in my file (let's call filter.rb), but I never get a Pry prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "pry"

n=0
while line=STDIN.gets do
 begin
   n=n+1
   raise "an exception" if n==2
 rescue => e
   binding.pry
 end
end
```

When I issue:

```
cat data.txt|ruby filter.rb
```

I see on the screen:

```
     5:   while line= STDIN.gets do
     6:    begin
     7:      n=n+1
     8:      raise "an exception" if n==2
     9:    rescue => e
 => 10:      binding.pry
    11:    end
    12:   end
```

But in fact all I get is a bash prompt, not a Pry command prompt.

Comment: If I run "ruby filter.rb" and I supply the standard input from my keyboard, ended with a Ctrl+D, it works. If I pipe form the file, it doesn't work again. Maybe my txt file contains some text or characters which causes Pry to exit.

Comment: Does your file have newlines in it?

Comment: Create a smaller file, or increase the number 2 in your if statement.  I believe that the piping of the file is causing pry to accept the additional lines.  Instead of using STDIN use a file for testing this.

Comment: Yes, it contains new lines, in fact it was a html file. And I tried with a text file too, same result (it contained such things in several lines: bla bla -> bla bla -> bla bla -> etc).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) uses [Readline](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html), which in turn reads from stdin. If you use ruby as a filter, stdin no longer is a terminal (isatty will be false). So Readline won't be able to use stdin and silently marches on (or gives a syntax error and marches on, if you're lucky).

You can give Readline a working tty by adding

```
require "readline"
Readline.input = IO.new(IO.sysopen("/dev/tty", "r+"))
```

to your code.

The Pry documentation hints at this solution, but I do not know if this is sanctioned by Pry, or if it could cause weird interactions with other parts of Pry, Ruby and whatever other moving bits you may have in your app... YMMV.

Comment: The readline fix is not working for me in Ruby 2.4.1. But this is: ```require 'pry'; 
pry_in = IO.new(IO.sysopen("/dev/tty", "r+")); 
Pry.config.input = pry_in; binding.pry```

Answer (score 0):

I think BertD's answer will work fine.

The *easiest* thing to do is to just read the file in normally,  (roughly) e.g.,

```
File.new("data.txt").each_line do |line|
  begin
    n += 1
    raise "an exception" if n == 2
  rescue => e
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

I'd also encourage encapsulating the processing in a class/method so *how* the data gets to the input is a separate issue of what *happens* to the data. It also makes debugging things in isolation much easier.

Comment: This is a clash of cultures! The Unix Way is to make everything a filter. The Ruby Way is not supposed to bite the Unix Way. I personally think it's a bug to have readline read from stdin instead of /dev/tty by default.

Comment: That said, I learned to seperate the OS interface from the business logic quickly after learning Ruby, precisely because minor imperfections like this Readline thing really punish old farts like me who barge in with their Perl mindsets -- and I feel enlightened as a result.
[sorry, got bitten by the binding of the Enter key to the Add Comment button; still learning about stackoverflow]